# CMake replacing a string while copying file

Tags: replace, cmake, copy, post-build

Hi there my project has job.sh in a root dir

the file contains

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=$(REPLACEME)
#SBATCH --tasks=4
#SBATCH --computers=1

run ./myApp
```

now I would like to somehow copy the file to builddir as well as replace $(REPLACEME) with Project name

not sure how to do the reeplacing part, as copying it easy

```
file(GENERATE OUTPUT job.sh INPUT job.sh)
```

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you create a template file like job.sh in root dir that contains what you want and some CMAKE variables like ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} for example

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
#SBATCH --tasks=4
#SBATCH --computers=1

run ./myApp
```

then in your CMakeLists.txt just do this

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/job.sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/job.sh)
```